# how to style style line chart points in c3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart, c3

I have a general c3js question. I'm trying to make the points in a C3JS line chart "hollow" (white fill, with a colored stroke), but am having a hard time figuring out how to do that. I've tried to add my own CSS, but it gets overwritten by the direct `style` tag in the html.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code relative to such points?

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` in your CSS to give it precedence over CSS styling from c3.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

or you can simply use the .c3-circle class as follow :

```
.c3-circle {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'd probably need to dip into the D3 code to manipulate them on the svg, something like this:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 5);
```